# Your credentials did not work Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I created a VM in windows Azure. At the time of creation I gave proper Username and Password, but when I try to connect that from Remote desktop I am getting following error "Your credentials did not work" I gave correct username and password. Do I need to do any further configurations/ can I reset my username or password ?

If some faced/solved this Issue please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. using \ before the name. so that it wont take default domain

Answer (score 1):

if you use a username in your password then the credentials will not work. for eg., if the username is xyz then the password should not contain xyz like xyz@123.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the Management Portal to create your VM and if you have left the default settings for the extensions (last page of the VM creation wizard), then the VM agent is installed on the VM and you can reset the admin account and Passwort using Windows PowerShell.

Using PowerShell use the command [Set-AzureVMAccessExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722527.aspx). With the parameters UserName and Password you can reset them.

Here is an [introductory article about that topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/03/06/enable-rdp-or-reset-password-with-the-vm-agent.aspx), that also explains how to check whether the VM agent is installed.