# Azure VM, your credentials did not work on remote desktop

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I've just had a bit of fun trying to connect to a new VM I'd created, I've found loads of posts from people with the same problem, the answer details the points I've found

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(1) For me it worked with

```
<VMName>\Username
Password
```

e.g.

```
Windows8VM\MyUserName
SomePassword@1
```

(2) Some people have just needed to use a leading '\', i.e.

```
\Username
Password
```

[Your credentials did not work Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506128/your-credentials-did-not-work-azure-vm)

(3) You can now reset the username/password from the app portal. There are powershell scripts which will also allow you to do this but that shouldn't be necessary anymore.

(4) You can also try redeploying the VM, you can do this from the app portal

(5) This blog says that "Password cannot contain the username or part of username", but that must be out of date as I tried that once I got it working and it worked fine

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/narahari/2011/08/29/your-credentials-did-not-work-error-when-connecting-to-windows-azure-vms/

(6) You may find links such as the below which mention Get-AzureVM, that seems to be for classic VMs, there seem to be equivalents for the resource manager VMs such as Get-AzureRMVM

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/03/06/enable-rdp-or-reset-password-with-the-vm-agent/

For complete novices to powershell, if you do want to go down that road here's the basics you may need. In the end I don't believe I needed this, just point 1

```
unInstall-Module AzureRM
Install-Module AzureRM -allowclobber
Import-Module AzureRM
Login-AzureRmAccount (this will open a window which takes you through the usual logon process)

Add-AzureAccount (not sure why you need both, but I couldn’t log on without this)

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId <the guid for your subscription>

Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName "<your RG name>" -VMName "Windows8VM" -Name "myVMAccess" -Location "northeurope" -username <username> -password <password>
```

(7) You can connect to a VM in a scale set as by default the Load Balancer will have Nat Rules mapping from port onwards 50000, i.e. just remote desktop to the IP address:port. You can also do it from a VM that isn't in the scale set. Go to the scale set's overview, click on the "virtual network/subnet", that'll give you the internal IP address. Remote desktop from the other one

Comment: I ran into similar issue just now. For me it was actually #5 from above: my password contained my username, although with different cases (username: xxadmin, pw: XXAdmin123), I did not receive an error in the PowerShell when creating the VM, but I got credential error when trying to login through RDP. I used the Reset Password feature in the Azure Portal to setup a completely different password, and I could login to RDP on first try.

Comment: For me it was 3). I had to reset the password.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into similar issues. It seems to need domain by default. Here is what worked for me:

localhost\username

Other option can be vmname\username

Some more guides to help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal#connect-to-virtual-machine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

In April 2022 "Password cannot contain the username or part of username" was the issue.
During the creation of VM in Azure, everything was alright but wasn't able to connect via RDP.

Answer (score 1):

Same in Nov 2022, you will be allowed to create a password that contains the user name but during login it will display the credential error. Removing the user name from the password fixed it.